# Disable Second Select Option When First Select Option Is Not Yet Selected in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

How can i disable my second select option and the input value when i haven't selected my first select option? In my case, my first select option is the "Select Ingredient". I have an event in the "Select Ingredient" which if subscribes and the result is success, then second select option and the input value should be enabled? Here the stackblitz code that i have made.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rgxfsa?file=app/app.component.ts

```
onSelectIngredient(event): void {
   const ingredient_id =  this.productForm.get('ingredient_id').value
    // this.subscription = this.ingredientService.selectIngredient(ingredient_id)
    // .subscribe(
    //       (data:any) => {
    //         this.ingredient = data;     
    //       },
    //       error => {
    //        console.log(error);
    //       })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially disable second form by following code:

```
this.productForm.controls["topping_id"].disable();
```

when first dropdown will change then enable control by following code:

```
this.productForm.controls["topping_id"].enable();
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen initially disable the topping_id control, then listen to ingredient_if selection by subscribing to its control valueChange Observable.

```
 this.productForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      ingredient_id: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      topping_id: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true }, Validators.required), // <- here initial disable
      input_value: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
 });

// listen to ingredient valueChange to enable the topping
this.productForm.get('ingredient_id').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (value) {
    this.productForm.get('topping_id').enable();
  } else {
    this.productForm.get('topping_id').setValue(null);
    this.productForm.get('topping_id').disable();
  }
});
```

When ingredient_id value is selected, then you can manually enable topping control.

[Here is a forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-um79qv)